# NoSuchMethodError at com.google.android.gms.model.MarkerOptions.alpha

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, nosuchmethoderror

I am trying to use the alpha method for my markers on my map. The whole program runs just fine without this method being invoked.

Here is the marker I am trying to use with alpha.

```
map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .alpha(0.7f) // ERROR HERE!
    .title("Administration Lillard")
    .position(adminLil));
```

---

Here is my Log Cat error:

```
Could not find method com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions.alpha, referenced from method com.gmail.kstandard.ucofyi.MapUCOActivity.onCreate
VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 9711: Lcom/google/android/gms/maps/model/MarkerOptions;.alpha (F)Lcom/google/android/gms/maps/model/MarkerOptions;
VFY: replacing opcode 0x74 at 0x0486
Shutting down VM
threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x417b3898)
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions.alpha
    at com.foo.ucofyi.MapUCOActivity.onCreate(MapUCOActivity.java:81)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

---

Any suggestions or links will be deeply appreciated.

The minimum SDK is 11 and the target SDK is 19

Comment: try to put .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)).alpha(0.7f) after .position(adminLil), maybe you have to use alpha method after icon description so it knows to apply alpha to icon

Comment: Still getting the same error as before. Thank you for trying.

Answer (score 0):

Although this doesn't worked for me on the first time, try to update your Google Play Services in SDK manager. After that, replace the lib that you are using with the updated lib.

What worked for me was uninstall the lib and install it again, both steps by SDK manager. Then I replaced the old lib that I was using by the new one and worked perfectly.